# Get value from one of the fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that gives:

```
orp      CategoryId     Category        City      

999         1           bouquets        city-a       
999         2           arrengmnt       city-b       
999         4           chocolate       city-c
```

I want to add in each row the number of shops having the category:

```
orp     CategoryId      Category        City      NoShops

999         1           bouquets        city-a       10
999         2           arrengmnt       city-b       14
999         4           chocolate       city-c       3
```

I need to get the CategoryId (@CategoryId), So I was thinking about something like this (obviously is't not working):

```
SELECT  Categories.OrderInPage as orp, CategoriesInLanguages.CategoryName,  @CategoryId = Categories.Id     
                ,(
                    SELECT COUNT(Shops.Id) as NoShops
                        FROM  Cities INNER JOIN
                                      CitiesInLanguages ON Cities.Id = CitiesInLanguages.CityId INNER JOIN
                                      ShopsInCities ON Cities.Id = ShopsInCities.CityId INNER JOIN
                                      CategoriesInLanguages INNER JOIN
                                      Categories ON CategoriesInLanguages.CategoryId = Categories.Id INNER JOIN
                                      ProductstInCategories ON Categories.Id = ProductstInCategories.CategoryId 
                        WHERE      (Products.IsEnable = 1)  AND ( Categories.Id = @CategoryId)) AS Z  
                )
        FROM  Cities INNER JOIN
                          CitiesInLanguages ON Cities.Id = CitiesInLanguages.CityId INNER JOIN
                          ShopsInCities ON Cities.Id = ShopsInCities.CityId INNER JOIN
                          CategoriesInLanguages INNER JOIN
                          Categories ON CategoriesInLanguages.CategoryId = Categories.Id INNER JOIN
                          ProductstInCategories ON Categories.Id = ProductstInCategories.CategoryId 
        WHERE      (Products.IsEnable = 1)
```

Comment: You can't combine data retrieval and variable assignment operations. Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do here? What is the point of returning a bunch of data in the select and then saving the value for later? If the query returns multiple rows, which value of col3 do you expect to be assigned to the variable?

Comment: @Eyal : Vote up, because you fixed your question!

Comment: You need to get WHICH CategoryId? To do what with? Since there are multiple rows in the query, which one do you expect to see in the variable? The requirement still doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have

```
Select col1, col2, col3 from table1
```

or

```
Select  @param1 = col1, @param2 =  col2, @param3 = col3 from table1 where id=value
```

and not both. Notice I added WHERE clause, your query should return 1 row to make use of @param

If you used the second option, you can then do the following

```
Select  @param1 as col1, @param2 as  col2, @param3 as col3
```

to return result

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix the two operations. If you try it, the error message is self-explanatory.

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be
>   combined with data-retrieval operations.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do something like:
`SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1 WHERE col3 = param`,
but not mixing two operations at the same time. I would assume this rule applies to Sql Server. However, it's now clear what are you trying to do. Could you please be more specific?